# How to match only two words?

Tags: java, regex

How can I match only two words that are separated by one or more spaces?

`[\w]+[\s]+[\w]+`

matches:

```
one two
one two three //but this should not match as it countains more than 2 words
```

Comment: What's wrong with the current regex?

Comment: as I wrote above: the content `one two three` matches. It should not as I want to find out if there are only two (and always two!) words in the string.

Comment: How are you using the regex? If using `matches()` method, then that should work fine.

Comment: @RohitJain I suspect he's testing the regex out with a regex tester first.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298566/regex-match-whole-string

Comment: http://java-regex-tester.appspot.com/ using "one two three" as target text, and "[\w]+[\s]+[\w]+" as regex, matches comes up false.

Comment: I used http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: @membersound java is different. Matches has to match the entire string, not just part of it. To match part of it you would use "find".

Comment: why not using a simpler `s.split(" ").size == 2` ?

Comment: Probably there was an intention why I asked for regex inspite of doing a java split. And indeed, I'd like to use it inside a hibernate validation annotation. But as it does not matter for the question itself, I ommited this information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this regex with line start and end anchors :

```
^\\s*\\w+\\s+\\w+\\s*$
```

Note use of `^` and `$` that makes sure only `two word string`, separated by space is matched.

#### RegEx Reference: http://regular-expressions.info

Comment: how could I add optional spaces in front and behind the two words?

Comment: @membersound: Check the update for matching optional spaces on either side.