# Match input field with pattern

Tags: javascript, html

Im using a java script method to check if fields are valid so that the form can continue. This works fine until it gets to the post code because that has to be a specific pattern .

Is there anyway to check if the value of the field matches the pattern and then allow the form to continue.

As you can see , its set to only let the form progress if the lengths are greater than 0 , which is not good for the form ,  but worse for the postcode part.

Javascript:

```
function processPhase2(){
houseN = _("Hnumber").value;
lineone = _("Caddress1").value;
linetwo = _("Caddress2").value;
cityC = _("Ccity").value;
countyC = _("Ccounty").value;
postalcodeC = _("Cpostalcode").value;
if(houseN.length > 0 && lineone.length > 0 && cityC.length > 0 && countyC.length > 0 && postalcodeC.length > 0){
    _("phase2").style.display = "none";
    _("phase3").style.display = "block";
    _("progressBar").value = 66;
    _("status").innerHTML = "Phase 3 of 3";
} else {

}
```

}

Input field:

```
    <label for="postalcode">Postal Code</label>
<input type="text" name="Cpostalcode" id="Cpostalcode" size="20" required pattern="[A-Za-z]{1,2}[0-9Rr][0-9A-Za-z]? [0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Zabd-hjlnp-uw-z]{2}" placeholder="eg: W1C 8LT" title="Must match pattern">
```

Comment: By "postcode" do you mean `postalCode` or are you actually talking to something that happens after the submit (post-code)?

Comment: Also, your code isn't using the `pattern` currently. Grab it with `getAttribute` and apply it to a `new RegExp(pattern)`. Then, you can just use the RegExp `test` method.

Comment: i mean Cpostalcode - This is the input field. how would i apply it to a new pattern . I dont really know javascript that well

Comment: Posted an answer to help explain. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grab the pattern with `getAttribute` and apply it to a `new RegExp(pattern)`. Then, you can just use the RegExp [`test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) method.

```
var elem = document.getElementById("Cpostalcode");

var pattern = elem.getAttribute("pattern");
var re = new RegExp(pattern);
if (re.test(elem.value)) {
    // Pattern matches!
} else {
    // Pattern does NOT match.
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cfalk/9jpt7pbg/)**

---

**Note: You should add the start (`^`) and end (`$`) characters to your pattern** or else it will test for substrings rather test than the entire string. You could do this with `var re = new RegExp("^"+pattern+"$")` or in the `pattern` attribute itself. ([More on that...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298566/regex-match-whole-string))

Comment: I assume that this would be separate to the original java script , so what would i put in the if statement in the original java script

Comment: Yep -- this is the few lines you'd need to validate at any given time. You could throw this in your function wherever you'd like (eg: in your `if` statement).

Comment: It looks like you're using Underscore as well, so you could probably shorten this a bit; this is the "pure JavaScript" version since I haven't played with Underscore yet. ;)

Comment: could i do this , if its true , it sets a variable to 1 or false to 0 . then in the if statement just test to see if that variable is true or false.

Comment: also i get cannot read property getAttribute of null in chrome

Comment: Yuppers to your first comment. You could also just set `var valid = re.test(...)`. And interesting, did you transfer the code correctly? Check out the JSFiddle. I'm also in chrome.

Comment: yh i copied it from the jsfiddle ,but still get it . Would a jsfiddle of the page im working on help

Comment: Yup! Sounds like it can't find the `id` of the element.

Comment: it kind of works - it dosent allow me to move onto the next part still - http://jsfiddle.net/oxhey/L11pmbLm/

Comment: Oh! You want to check against the pattern *every time* you validate; right now you are only checking when the page loads (which doesn't actually matter). Throw all of the postal-code validation stuff into your `processPhase2` function. Make sense?

Comment: just seen that , its better but when i enter a postcode that should be valid , it still says pattern dosent match and dosent allow it to go forward

Comment: Are you sure the pattern attribute is correct, then? Try throwing it in http://regexpal.com to check

Comment: Oh! It should be `.value` and not `.val` -- typo on my part. My apologies! answer updated.

Comment: the test data highlited yellow , so i guess its correct

Comment: No prob. Regex is a very useful tool to know. : )