# Jquery - changing input background css based on in array results

Tags: php, jquery, css, arrays

I have this array :

```
    array = ['08','06','05','03','123456'];
```

when I enter values into a text input I'm checking if there are in the array. This appears to be working.. but I'm finding it's matching on 07 and 123 as well as the values in the array.

```
$(function() {
 $('#do').on('input', function() {

        array = ['08','06','05','03','123456'];
        do = $(this).val();

        if ($.inArray(do, array) > -1) {
            $(this).css('background-color', '#FFFFFF');
            console.log (do + ' - ' + array + ' - not found');
        } else {
            $(this).css('background-color', '#FAFAFA');
            console.log (do + ' - ' + array + ' - found');
        }
      });
    });
```

I've created a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4qtz5xnr/)**, to show this.

All I'm trying to do is change the css background of the input if the value entered in `'do'` matches any whole value in the array. If it doesn't match then change the background white.

The array values are coming from php and are formatted as :
`['08','06','05','03','123456']`

I can change the array layout if needed.

Can any one advise what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: First, you should change the variable `do` to something else, as `do` is a JavaScript keyword. Secondly, are there any console errors in the code?

Comment: Thanks I can change that.  No console errors logged at all.

Comment: Use regex match http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298566/regex-match-whole-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

my first guess was wrong, so i completely changed this answer. `$.inArray()` evaluates to `-1` if the value is not found. otherwise it returns the index of the found value in the array.
so you have got an error in your `if` condition. just compare using `== -1`:

```
$(function () {
    $('#do').on('input', function () {

        var my_array = ['08', '06', '05', '03', '123456'];
        var x = $(this).val();

        if ($.inArray(x, my_array) == -1) {
            $(this).css('background-color', '#f00');
            $("#feedback").text(x + ' - ' + my_array + ' - not found');
        } else {
            $(this).css('background-color', '#0f0');
            $("#feedback").text(x + ' - ' + my_array + ' - found');
        }
    });
});
```

updated fiddle with more debug-functionality:

http://jsfiddle.net/4qtz5xnr/3/