# Matching several alternatives as whole strings only using pipe OR operator

Tags: regex

I am trying to find the proper regular expression for checking the following:

Option 1: Integer (e.g. 100, 200, 1, 0, 15, 300000)

Option 2: N/A (matching case)

I tried with "^\d+$|(N/A)", but I need an exclusive OR condition (only one option is possible, right now I have matching for case "100 N/A"):

- 100: True
- 100.02: False
- N/A: True
- n/a: False
- 100 N/A: False
- N/A 100: False

Comment: FYI only: your current regex fails because for `1 N/A`, the left hand side fails (finding digits only from start to end) but the right hand side succeeds because the string *does* contain `N/A` somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an outer grouping with the alternation operator:

```
^(\d+|N/A)$
```

The `/` might need escaping in the code if `/` regex delimiters are required (as in Ruby or JS regex literals). You may also use a non-capturing group to only group the alternatives without capturing the data into subgroups: `^(?:\d+|N/A)$`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vEOcbO/1%5C)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(` - start of a grouping construct (so that the `^` and `$` anchors round it could be applied to all the alternatives):

  - `\d+` - 1+ digits
  - `|` - or
  - `N/A` - an `N/A` substring
- `)` - end of the grouping construct
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: @JohanWentholt I doubt this question is Ruby specific, I just noted that `/` might need escaping in cases when `/` is used as a regex delimiter. If a language tag is added, then I will adjust the answer. In C, with `<regex.h>`, `$` won't work without a certain flag, but I am not adding this to the answer.

Comment: I know this question isn't Ruby specific. I'm not saying you should change your answer since escaping `/` might be a concern. I just provided an alternate method of creating the regex in Ruby, since you named that language in your answer as example. My points still remain valid.

Comment: @JohanWentholt Then I should also add that in JS users may write `new RegExp("^(?:\\d+|N/A)$")` or `var rx = /^(?:\d+|N\/A)$/`. Although that is just adding more and more notes. Mentioning the **regex literals** concept is enough here.

Comment: It doesn't belong in the answer, but in a comment under the answer I see no problem.