# Regular Expression phone number not working

Tags: jquery, regex, format

Here is my code

```
var _phonenumber = '09000000000';
if _phonenumber.match(/\A0[5789]0\d{8}\z/)
  console.log('valid');
else
  console.log('invalid)';
```

But if I input correct phone, it still print invalid `09000000000`

Comment: The test() method tests for a match in a string. This method returns true if it finds a match, otherwise it returns false.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex - Match whole string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298566/regex-match-whole-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The match() method retrieves the matches when matching a string against a regular expression.

If the string matches the expression, it will return an Array containing the entire matched string as the first element, followed by any results captured in parentheses. If there were no matches, null is returned.

In your case, you are missing the parenthesis around match.

```js
var _phonenumber = '09000000000';
if(_phonenumber.match(/\A0[5789]0\d{8}\z/))
  console.log('valid');
else
  console.log('invalid');
  
console.log(_phonenumber.match(/\A0[5789]0\d{8}\z/));
```

> The test() method executes a search for a match between a regular expression and a specified string. Returns true or false.

Using `test()` will be better for your use case.

```js
var _phonenumber = '09000000000';
if(/\A0[5789]0\d{8}\z/g.test(_phonenumber))
  console.log('valid');
else
  console.log('invalid');
```

Comment: It's should valid

Comment: The output is correct as your regex doesn't have `\A` in the beginning and `\z` at the end.

Comment: @HungNguyen you can accept the answer see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers