# How to write a regex which matches anything but a number

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create an angular directive to be used with HTML inputs to filter out none numeric characters

Here is my regex I am using to achieve that:

`inputValue.replace(/[^0-9\-\.]/g, "").replace(/\.(\.)/g, '$1');`

However this regex does not cover these cases:

- `--5`
- `5.5.6`
- `-5-5`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex - Match whole string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298566/regex-match-whole-string)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, this is really simple.^^

```
\d
```

`\d` machtes every digit from `[0-9]`. You can test our RegEx very simple at https://regex101.com without writing any javascript code to test it.

Edit:

You might want to add a `*` to the `\d`.

```
\d*
```

The `*` is the greedy selector, which selects all of the type before.

Answer (score 0):

In your regex you use a negated character class `[^0-9\-\.]` which matches not a digit 0-9, a `-` and a `.` so you are keeping those matches.

If you want to match anything but a number you could use `[^0-9]` or [`\D`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) to match any character that is not a digit and replace that with an empty value.

```js
let inputValue = `--5
5.5.6
-5-5
!@#$%# $%@% $%435 452545`;
inputValue = inputValue.replace(/\D/g, "");
console.log(inputValue);
```