# Validation Regex to disallow a single digit 0

Tags: regex, dojo

I've tried many examples to **disallow** a single digit `0`. The closest one working is `[^0]` but that matches on `20`, `30`, etc. I only want to match on `0`.

Comment: Please, provide *examples*. For instance, which of `"0"`, `"0.0"`, `"-0"`, `"+0"`, `"00"`, `"zero: 0"`, `"0-0-0"`, `"   0   "` (spaces) should be matched?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex - Match whole string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298566/regex-match-whole-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match not a zero but do want to allow positive and negative numbers you might use. This uses anchors `^` and `$` to assert the start and the end of the string.

[`^[+-]?[1-9][0-9]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/gESVfn/1)

Without using anchors you could use a word boundary `\b`:

[`[+-]?\b[1-9][0-9]*\b`](https://regex101.com/r/iA9DF9/1)

That would match an optional plus or minus sign `[+-]?`, a digit from 1 - 9 `[1-9]` so it does not match a zero followed by zero or more times a digit `[0-9]*`

Comment: This could be nitpicking :-) but it allows `0.0`. That wasn't in the question but would seem to be in the spirit of it to also disallow that.

Comment: @The fourth bird - Thank you!  That did it.  I was pulling my hair out.

Comment: @PeterB Are you sure this matches `0.0`? [test 1](https://regex101.com/r/gESVfn/2) and [test 2](https://regex101.com/r/iA9DF9/2)

Answer (score 2):

Use start and end anchors to match the entire input being a zero:

```
^0$
```

Or to match a solitary zero within a string, use word boundaries:

```
\b0\b
```

Do *disallow* a solitary zero in the input use the above in a negative look ahead.

```
^(?!.*\b0\b).*
```

Comment: Thanks Bohemian. I'm trying to use 'regExp' with data-dojo-props to not allow '0' in the field although both positive and negative numbers are allowed.  When using ^0$, it 'matches' on any number (5,6,7,etc).

data-dojo-props="constraints:{min:-90,max:90,places:0}, required:true, invalidMessage:'Latitude degree is -90 to 90',
        regExp:'^0$', invalidMessage:'Latitude degree cannot be 0'"  /> deg&nbsp;&nbsp;

Comment: @JWK I think your code sample should be in the original question, so please *[edit it!](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50525218/edit)* It helps to show a lot better what you are trying to achieve.