# Creating a regex to match numbers or a range of number

Tags: regex

I've been looking at regex help pages but cant seem to find/understand a solution.

My problem is: I want a regex that allows either specifically a number or a range of numbers that will be integrated in a code for data input validation. For example one can only input either "12" or "12-50" with that exact same format, no extra dashes or anything.

The solution I created for the ex."12-50" is `[0-9][-][0-9]` and works perfectly fine. However I can't integrate the above regex with one that will allow that format and also the format of just a single number.

I tried using the OR operator, `[0-9]|[0-9][-][0-9]`, however it doesn't seem to work perfectly as I can input "incorrect formats" such as "12-","123---" etc.

Comment: Have the dash and the two following digits be an optional group? `/\d\d(-\d\d)?/`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Match whole string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298566/match-whole-string)

Comment: Tried ^[0-9]$|^[0-9][-][0-9]$ however its not working. I'm sorry but I'm new at using regex.

Comment: Try ^(([0-9]+)|([0-9]+[-][0-9]+))$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly `[0-9][-][0-9]` is not matching the whole of "12-50", just the "2-5" substring. And that explains your false positives: in each case the regex is matching a substring.

Therefore you need to start by matching the whole string: `^…$`.

Also, you want sequences of digits rather than single digits so say that: `\d+` matches one or more digits ('\d' matches a digit<sup>[1]</sup>).

So something like:

```
^\d+(-\d+)?$
```

should work. Expanding this

```
^         Start of string
\d+       One or more digits
(         Start of group
   -\d+   Dash followed by one or more digits
)         End of group
?         Preceding element – the group – is optional
$         End of string
```

---

<sup>[1]</sup> it, depending on your specific regex engine, may match non-ASCII digits from Unicode, but you'll need to check your documentation for that.

Answer (score 0):

As you want exact match pattern, you need to use start and ending indicator.

> ^ : Indicate starting
>
> $ : Indicate ending
>
> | : To give more than one regex using or condition
>
> '+' : To find atleast one accurance

```
^(([0-9]+)|([0-9]+[-][0-9]+))$
```