# Match a single Regex character that is within a certain range

Tags: javascript, regex

Seems quite simple, but I can't find how to do this. I want to match a single character within a certain range, say a to z.

> [a-z]

Currently doing the following:

```
const regex = RegExp('[a-z]');
console.warn('TEST', regex.test('a'))
```

Simple enough. However I want it to be a single character. If there is any more than one, regardless if they also belong in that range, it needs to fail.
So for example:

- `a` should pass
- `b` should pass
- `ab` should fail
- `aa` should fail
- `abcdefg` should fail

You get the idea.

I have tried some variations such asL

> [{1}a-z]

Which doesn't do anything. Ultimately it still accepts any combination of character within that range.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Match whole string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298566/match-whole-string)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pin the string down using `^` and `$`, which match the "start of string" and the "end of string", respectively.

Your regex would be `^[a-z]$`, which means you expect to match a single character between `a` and `z`, and that single character must be the entire string to match.

The reason `[a-z]{1}` (which is equivalent to `[a-z]`) doesn't work is because you can match single characters all along the string.  The start/end of the string aren't "pinned down".

```js
let str = ['a','b','ab','aa','abcdefg'];
const regex = /^[a-z]$/;
str.forEach(w => console.warn(w, regex.test(w)));
```

By the way, `[{1}a-z]` doesn't do what you think it does.  You intended to match a single alphabetic character, but this adds three more characters to the match list, which becomes:

- a-z
- `{`
- `}`
- `1`.

I think you meant `[a-z]{1}`, which as previously noted is equivalent to `[a-z]`.