# Regex match against array of values

Tags: javascript

Currently I have this:

```
const illegals = [/Foo/, /Bar/, /FooBar/];
var testTxt = "Foo Fighter";
var isMatch = illegals.some(rx => rx.test(testTxt));
```

and since the testTxt contains 'Foo' it returns true. But I only want to match if it matches the full text (i.e. 'Foo Fighter') otherwise return false. What have I got wrong here?

Comment: Make the regular expressions check the entire input by using the anchors `^` and `$`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Match whole string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298566/match-whole-string)

Comment: This might be a highly simplified example; if not, you could also just use [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) for simplicity: `illegals.contains(testTxt);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like Vlaz already put in his comment, you need to include `^`and 
`$` before and after your pattern to signal that you want to match the whole string.

```js
const illegals = [/^Foo$/, /^Bar$/, /^FooBar$/];
var testTxt = "Foo Fighter";
console.log(illegals.some(rx => rx.test(testTxt)))     // false
console.log(illegals.some(rx => rx.test('Bar')))       // true
console.log(illegals.some(rx => rx.test('Bar stool'))) // false
console.log(illegals.some(rx => rx.test('FooBar')))    // true
```

Comment: ahh ok, I was missing the stupid anchors, duh, need more coffee, thanks!

Comment: Wow, I honestly don't get it! :-) How does this _simplest of all answers_ suddenly get 4 upvotes, when some of my other answers where I found myself researching and working on for hours don't even get a single one?!? :D :D :D - Well, I guess these "reputation" points mustn't be taken too seriously. ;-)