# # and ^ should not match in this regular expression /([a-zA-Z][^a-zA-Z]*){3,}/ in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

The minimum string length should be 3 and it should not contain `#` and `^` in the string

I tried with `/([a-zA-Z][^a-zA-Z#^]*){3,}/`, It's working on https://regexr.com, but its not working all testing tools like https://www.regextester.com .

Comment: What characters _should_ the string contain?

Comment: Most likely a duplicate of: [Match exact string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6298566)

Comment: The pattern matches 3 or more times matching a single char a-zA-Z followed by optional chars other than `a-zA-Z#^` and works on both testing tools. Why would it not work?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen except of # and ^ , all char is allowed. first char should not space

Comment: @Thefourthbird please send proper regex and both testing tools

Comment: If the minimum length should be 3, then `^[a-zA-Z][^a-zA-Z#^]{2,}$` See https://regexr.com/71fee and https://regex101.com/r/4vVml2/1

Comment: Or `^[a-zA-Z][^#^]{2,}$`

Answer (score 2):

**EDITED:** `^(?![^a-zA-Z0-9])[^#^]{3,}$` should do the work if you just want to:

- match a string containing characters except `#` and `^`
- has a length of at least 3 characters
- only let alphanumerics be the first char

Comment: It is taking space as a first char, but it should not be allowed

Comment: @manishk that's not what your question said: "*The minimum string length should be 3 and it should not contain # and ^ in the string*" and [you didn't clarify when you were asked what it should contain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74285574/and-should-not-match-in-this-regular-expression-a-za-za-za-z3-i/74285666?noredirect=1#comment131149083_74285574). Please think *carefully* about your questions before you ask them. You've been given an answer based on what you asked, not based on information that was not presented.

Comment: @VLAZ it is a common thing, string will not take the first char as a space normally

Comment: @manishk, strings in programming have a very large chance to start with a space character, especially when you trying to combine two strings: `"Posted"+" at yesterday"`. It's not such "a common thing". If you wish to not include space has first char, you should specify the requirements in the question, pls review my edit.

Comment: @Henryc17 sorry for the one more test case, actually it should start with a number or char only, not with special char, in between of string special char we can use except for # and ^, thanks for support!

Comment: @manishk, Ive made another edit, pls take a look.