# Replace text based on fixed mapping

Tags: r, string, dplyr, stringr

I am trying to replace simple sample names with more complex text. The problem is described below

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(clipr)
library(ggpubr)
library(KernSmooth)
library(reshape2)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(stringr) 

df <- df %>%
  mutate(across('Sample', str_replace, 'A', 'Cat')) %>%
  mutate(across('Sample', str_replace, 'B', 'Dog')) %>%
  mutate(across('Sample', str_replace, 'C', 'Bat'))
```

What I get

A = Batat (because the C in cat gets replaced with "Bat")

How do I only replace text that contains "A" and "A" only?
I've spent a couple hours now trying to solve this issue, which seems really basic.

Comment: Check out [`case_match`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_match.html) and [this regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298566/match-exact-string)

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need ‘stringr’ at all here, you can use direct lookup or indirect loop (based on `match()`):

```
old = c('A', 'B', 'C')
new = c('Cat', 'Dog', 'Bat')

df |> mutate(Sample = new[match(Sample, old)])
```

Or:

```r
mapping = c(A = 'Cat', B = 'Dog', C = 'Bat')
# Or, if you can’t hard-code the values:
mapping = setNames(new, old)

df |> mutate(Sample = mapping[Sample])
```

(The above uses `mutate()` from ‘dplyr’ but the same approach can be used without ‘dplyr’, since we’re just modifying a vector.)

Comment: @benson23 This seems irrelevant/distracting, since OP already included the package into their question, and `mutate()` isn’t the point of this answer — it can be solved without.

Comment: But I guess it'd be better for future visitors if they don't already know the package (because you've used `mutate` in the answer)? I mean you are more experienced here than I do, you can revert the edit if you think it's inappropriate, I'm trying to help a bit only :)

Comment: This worked (at least the mapping approach). I think the first approach failed because I have multiple instances of A, B, C etc in df. (this is just an example, don't want to share my actual data info)

Comment: @brtw Ah, that was a typo (fixed now): now the first code also works with different data.

Comment: Note to other users -when using "mapping = setNames(new, old)" the order of the vector should match the order of the IDs in the df. It should be alphabetically sorted according to the old IDs, otherwise it replaces the incorrect ID. This caused me some problems :(.

Answer (score 0):

Konrad's answer I believe is the way to do it, but just as a point of comparison, here are some other ways of getting to the same result:

1. Turn `Sample` into a factor column (I'm guessing based on the names 'A', 'B', 'C' etc., this is already the case, just unstated?)

```
df |> mutate(Sample = factor(Sample, levels = c('A', 'B', 'C'), labels = new))
```

2. create a conversion dataframe, left join the dataframe on the conversion dataframe, and select the columns you require:

```
convdf <- data.frame(old = c('A', 'B', 'C'), new = c('Cat', 'Dog', 'Bat'))

left_join(df, convdf, by = c('Sample' = 'old')) |> select(Sample = new)
```

3. Check for word boundaries in the `str_replace()` call:

```
df |> mutate(Sample = str_replace_all(Sample, setNames(new, paste0("\\b", old, "\\b"))))
```

4. Swap the order around:

```
df %>%
  mutate(across('Sample', str_replace, 'B', 'Dog')) %>%
  mutate(across('Sample', str_replace, 'C', 'Bat')) %>%
  mutate(across('Sample', str_replace, 'A', 'Cat'))
```

The issue is that `str_replace, 'A', 'Cat'` creates a capital C which is used by the later `str_replace, 'C', 'Bat'`. If we swap them around so this doesn't happen, then we are okay (note: this one is quite janky, so not the best solution!)