# Can i use /^USA$/ for a exact match? is it safe? any better idea?

Tags: javascript, cpu-word

I have  my_string of my_text_field (but its hidden), for example, FRANCE USA_ILANDS GERMANY (space between these each country / words.....actually, all these country names are NAMES of text fields/drop-downs/check boxes on my_form) like that i am concatenating around 200 countrries, well.

Now, i want to search for a match in my_string, say for example, am looking to search for a match of USA, so i put the below JS,

```
var myCountryName = /USA/; 

var returnValue = my_text_field.search(myCountryName);

if(returnValue != -1){; // This Country/field/object is found in the my_text_field, hence greyed out with readOnly
this.ui.oneOfChild.border.fill.color.value = "192,192,192";
this.access = "readOnly";
};
```

I am expecting the return value should be false.

But, its coming as true!

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447250/matching-exact-string-with-j avascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447250/matching-exact-string-with-j%20avascript)

Am following the first suggested option with place holders like, var r = /^a$/ its working fone for me

Pls. let me know is this is safe? ok? recommendabale? or Any other help to find out exact match word?

Thank you

Comment: is it syntax error? pls. eloborate how its?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`\b`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_begin.asp) to check for [word boundaries](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_begin.asp) on each side.

```
/\bUSA\b/
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually, i put it as in my original question as /^USA$/ and already integration team put in the list for sending it to production.....so, do you think my syntax is not safe? if not safe, now i need to coordinate  with integration folks to ask to stop sending my change to production and i need to implement your suggestion (\b \b)....pls. let me know, mine is not safe? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if USA exists then why not use:

```
my_text_field = ' '+my_text_field+' ';
my_text_field.indexOf(' '+myCountryName+' ');
```

Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: And if it is the first item or last?

Comment: Good point. I edited the code to pad the string. I guess my bigger point is that indexOf() is probably a more efficient way of getting the same simple result.

Comment: Your welcome. Sometimes it's the simple things that get you. :-)

Comment: Today i posted a question.....but no body is answering...is it bcz of my reputation went minus (-2)? so, once user goes minus reputation, then nobody will asnwer? My question is....................http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12955956/how-to-check-the-object-existence-validity