# Regex - accept only numbers between 1 and 100 (shouldnot accept anything else)

Tags: regex

I have the regex that accept number between 1 and 100. But it accepting the special character '%'

This is the regex that I am using

```
^(0*100{1,1}\\.?((?<=\\.)0*)?%?$)|(^0*\\d{0,2}\\.?((?<=\\.)\\d*)?%?)$'
```

I dont want to accept %
Can anyone please help me in fixing this.

Comment: What about leading zeros: `001`  ?

Comment: no leading zeros. it can be between 1 to 100. user can enter 1 to 3 digits between 1 to 100..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The regular expression suggested by [Ali Shah Ahmed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1559072/ali-shah-ahmed) doesn't work with 1 digit numbers, this one does:

```
(100)|(0*\d{1,2})
```

Edited: If you don't want to accept the value 0 you can use this regular expression:

```
(100)|[1-9]\d?
```

Comment: this accepts `1000` in JS, `(^100$)|^[1-9]\d?$` is 1-100

Comment: @vbranden 2nd regex is valid in javascript.

Comment: its valid but it allows 1000 which is outside the bounds of the OP's requirement that it only be 1 - 100 https://regex101.com/r/vS0pY7/1

Comment: @vbranden sorry but I don't understand - I tried the regex in 3 different javascript regex testers and all matched `100`, not `1000`. Last zero is not matched.

Comment: put it this way, if you do `if (numberString.match(/(100)|[1-9]\d?/)) { myFunction() }` and the numberString is `1000` then `myFunction` will be called. because it only matches 100 does not mean that other numbers are no accepted. how would the user know if `numberString` is between 1 and 100 if numbers 1 - infinity are matched?

Comment: Obviously if you need the validate the whole string you might need to use the start and end delimiters - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298566/regex-match-whole-string

Comment: @vbranden this is probably what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/a/447258/558486

Comment: @vbranden I think what you need is http://stackoverflow.com/a/42060770/1736092 which would not match for `I have 1000 dollars` in your example and includes samples for JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

Remove all the `%?`. This indicates that the regex should match zero or one `%` characters.

Comment: I removed %?. Just now I found that I could enter '0' too. can you please tell how not to allow 0 (zero)

Comment: I dont want to accept zero. but from 1 to 100. sorry for the wrong thing in the title

Answer (score 1):

I would take a multi-step approach.  Wouldn't try and solve this with a regex alone.  The maintenance is a nightmare.

My solution:-

Use a simple regex to determine whether the value is an integer with three or less digits.

```
/^\d{1,3}$/
```

If valid, cast to a number.

Check to see that the number is `<= 100` and `>= 0`.

Comment: I can do this in my Controller code. But jsut want to try using REGEX

Answer (score 1):

i believe this regex will also work, and is bit simpler than the one you mentioned.

```
(100)|(0*\d{1,2})
```

this will take care of leading zeros as well.

Comment: Your regex fails if the number has only 1 digit. The correct regex would be: `(100)|(0*\d{1,2})`

Answer (score 1):

This matches only 1 to 100 inclusive:
`/\b((100)|[1-9]\d?)\b/`

The `\b` matches word boundaries. This means something like in JavaScript:
`/((100)|[1-9]\d?)/.test("I have 1000 dollars");`
would return `true`. Instead, using the word boundaries would return `false`.

Answer (score 0):

This allows numbers from 1 to 100:

```
100|[1-9]?\d
```

Answer (score 0):

**^(100|[1-9][0-9]?)$** 
This regular expression matches between 1 to 100,
100 matches exactly 100 or 
[1-9] matches a character in the range 1 to 9
[0-9] matches a character in the range 0 to 9
? matches between 0 and 1 of the preceding token

and for your reference validate the regular expression combinations here https://regexr.com/

Answer (score 0):

Whatever others said is fine.

I am giving a complete and more precise code for the above asked question.
Hope it helps.

```
    const onChange = (userInput) => {
    const regex = /^([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|100)$/;
    if (userInput === "" || regex.test(userInput)) {
      console.log("valid number and in range of 1-100");
    } else {
      console.log("not a number and in range of 1-100");
    }
  };
```