# pe:keyfilter not working

Tags: regex, jsf-2, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

I need regex for primefaces keyfilter to allow input between 0-100 for percentage.

I tried lot of expression but none seems working.

I need my inputbox not to allow typing apart from 0-100.  Any suggestions

Comment: Please read [ask] then [mcve] and http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info and improve your question accordingly. And read them good... things about code examples and what you tried etc..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14622077/regex-accept-only-numbers-between-1-and-100-shouldnot-accept-anything-else