# Want to return true or false when finding an exact match in an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a posList that contains an array of objects. I want to check if the entered value is an exact match of all the posCode in each object of the posList. My RegExp returns true when its a search match. For example, when 4325
is entered it returns true. I only want it to return true if the match is exact.

```
//short example
posList = [
    {
        posCode: "43252",
        description: "hi"
    },
    {
        posCode: "HTD632",
        description: "hello"
    }
]

checkPosCodeUnique = () => {
    const re = new RegExp(_.escapeRegExp(this.state.posCode), 'i');
    const isMatch = result => (re.test(result.posCode));
    const list = _.filter(this.state.posList, isMatch);
    if (list.length > 0) {
        error=true;
    }

};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matching exact string with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447250/matching-exact-string-with-javascript)

Comment: is your list really large (much larger than your example)...if so, you might want to use a dictionary of key value pairs, so you hit on an exact match really fast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need to use regex?

```js
posList = [{
    posCode: "43252",
    description: "hi"
  },
  {
    posCode: "HTD632",
    description: "hello"
  }
]

checkPosCodeUnique = (search) => {
  return posList.some(item => { return item.posCode == search });
};

console.log(checkPosCodeUnique('43252'));
console.log(checkPosCodeUnique('HTD632'));
console.log(checkPosCodeUnique(123));
```

Comment: Thank you this is great! Was overthinking it!

Answer (score 1):

Use `some` method of arrays:

`console.log(posList.some(pos => pos.posCode.toUpperCase() === this.state.posCode.toUpperCase());`

Answer (score 1):

For what you describe, you don't need regular expressions, you can simply filter the list:

```
posList.filter(e => e.posCode === posCode)
```

See https://codesandbox.io/s/5w95r4zmvl for an implementation of your version and the one using a simple filter.