# Check if a string contains exact match

Tags: javascript

I want to check if a string `(let entry)` contains exact match with `let expect`:

```js
let expect = 'i was sent'
let entry = 'i was sente to earth' // should return false
// let entry = 'to earth i was sent' should return true

// includes() using the first instance of the entry returns true
if(entry.includes(expect)){
console.log('exact match')

} else {
console.log('no matches')

}
```

There are lots of answers on StackOverflow but I can't find a working solution.

**Note:**

```
let expect = 'i was sent' 
let entry = 'to earth i was sent'
```

should return true

```
let expect = 'i was sent' 
let entry = 'i was sente to earth'
```

should return false

Comment: Do you want to see if it contains or is an exact match?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/447258/5132337

It gives the correct answer.

Comment: let expect = 'i was sent'
let entry = 'i was sent e to earth' // should return false or true

Comment: um so `entry === expect`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matching exact string with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447250/matching-exact-string-with-javascript)

Comment: @foxer does "exact match" mean what it says, or would it just **containing** that string come back true also? I'm a bit confused....do you want to actually match a string exactly, or are you looking for the regex to identify that specific string somewhere in the string being passed as the arg?

Comment: I want to check if it containing the `expect` exactly,  I think the `includes()` checks containing  only that's why `let entry = 'i was sente to earth'` returns true unexpectedly...

Comment: Do you know what includes does exactly?? *update "The includes() method determines whether one string may be found within another string, returning true or false as appropriate."*  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes So it is true because the substring exists inside of the string.

Comment: Ok fair enough, updated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems like you're talking about matching word boundary, which can be accomplished using `\b` assertion in `RegExp` which *matches word boundary*, so there you go:

```js
const escapeRegExpMatch = function(s) {
    return s.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
};
const isExactMatch = (str, match) => {
  return new RegExp(`\\b${escapeRegExpMatch(match)}\\b`).test(str)
}

const expect = 'i was sent'

console.log(isExactMatch('i was sente to earth', expect)) // <~ false
console.log(isExactMatch('to earth i was sent', expect)) // <~ true
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Hello, this fails when string contains {([ 
for example : isExactMatch("09.12.06.Inkigayo.f(x) - Chu.tp", "f(x)") // false

Answer (score 2):

I have not tested this but you need to convert the expected to an array of strings and then check if all items are in the entry string.

```
let arr = expect.split(" ");
if (arr.every(item => entry.includes(item)) {
  console.log("match");
}
else.....
```